# Mongo text search within field

Tags: arrays, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I"ve a requirement to search for a text within a field in a particular document.
Consider the following doc...

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59cc8af23b86730a2c9a603f"),
    "social_friends" : {
            "google" : [
                {
                    "name" : "User one",
                    "id" : "1003153275"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "user two",
                    "id" : "10210778"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "user three",
                    "id" : "115131"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "user four",
                    "id" : "117113"
                }
            ]
    }
```

In which I want to search for an user by "name", 
say for eg: If I search "four", I would like to have result as

```
{
   "name" : "user four",
   "id" : "117113"
}
```

I've tried by creating text indexes and searched by

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"user four"}}).pretty()
```

but it is searching throughout all the documents inside the collection and it return multiple documents,

Then I've filtered using "_id"

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"user four"},"_id" : ObjectId("59cc8af23b86730a2c9a603f")}).pretty()
```

but it returns the whole document not the sub doc like below.

```
{
       "name" : "user four",
       "id" : "117113"
 }
```

First of all, Is it possible to do this? As I'm new to Mongo any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a partial solution that might help or atleast guide you towards a full solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{$text:{$search:"user four"}}},
    {$unwind:"$social_friends.google"},
    {$match:{"social_friends.google.name":"user four"}},
    {$project:{"doc":"$social_friends.google"}}
])
```

Also, if you just want to grab the first matched document, just add `{ $limit : 5 }`
Same for your normal `find` query.

If you want to filter using `_id`, use the following for the first match:

```
{$match:{_id:ObjectId("59cc8af23b86730a2c9a603f"),$text:{$se‌​arch:"user four"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah it prints multiple docs matches the search text, can we filter using "_id" ?

Comment: yes, you can just add the `_id` field in the match section.
`{$match:{_id:ObjectId("59cc8af23b86730a2c9a603f"),$text:{$search:"user four"}}}`